# yii2 how to create and condition in another one

Tags: sql, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I want to add filter condition with yii2 framework, and this condition have to generate the following request :

```
select count(*) from v_ressource
where 
(
    (
        str_to_date('27/04/2016', '%d/%m/%Y')
        between str_to_date(erDateDebut, '%d/%m/%Y')
        and str_to_date(erDateFin, '%d/%m/%Y')
    )
    and erDateFin is not null
)
or
(
    (
        str_to_date('27/04/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') 
        between str_to_date(erDateDebut, '%d/%m/%Y') 
        and now()
    )
    and erDateFin is null
);
```

As you can see there are 'and' conditions into the 'or' condition.

I have the following code in my ModelSearch :

```
    $query
        ->andFilterWhere([
            'between',
            'str_to_date(\'' . $this->dateRecherche . '\', \'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i\')',
            new Expression('str_to_date(erDateDebut, \'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i\')'),
            new Expression('str_to_date(erDateFin, \'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i\')'),
        ])
        ->andFilterWhere([
            'not', ['erDateFin' => null],
        ]);

    $query
        ->orFilterWhere([
            'between',
            'str_to_date(\'' . $this->dateRecherche . '\', \'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i\')',
            new Expression('str_to_date(erDateDebut, \'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i\')'),
            new Expression('now()'),
        ])
        ->andFilterWhere([
            'is', 'erDateFin', null,
        ]);
```

Both of is null and is not null conditions does not appear in the generated request and there isn't "nested" conditions (and condition in the or conditions)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't understand the between condition. The first operand (after 'between') should be a database column name. Now it seems to be a string with a mysql expression. Also I don't get the use of str_to_date. If the columns have type DateTime in the database (Schema::TYPE_DATETIME in Yii migration) there is no need of str_to_date. Could you give some more details on your model attributes and the related database column types?

Comment: It is ok you don't understand I had troubles with many-to-many relation queries so I decided to create a model based on a view. In that view I stored dates in french format. So that's why i use the str_to_date to compare date :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`andFilterWhere` and `orFilterWhere` doesn't allow nesting this way since they operate on the query object - not on a condition object. You could define your query this way:

```
$query->where(
    ['and',
        [
            'between',
            'str_to_date(\'' . $this->dateRecherche . '\', \'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i\')',
            new Expression('str_to_date(erDateDebut, \'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i\')'),
            new Expression('str_to_date(erDateFin, \'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i\')'),
        ],
        [
            'not', ['erDateFin' => null],
        ]
    ]);

$query->orWhere(
    ['and',
        [
            'between',
            'str_to_date(\'' . $this->dateRecherche . '\', \'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i\')',
            new Expression('str_to_date(erDateDebut, \'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i\')'),
            new Expression('now()'),
        ],
        [
            'is', 'erDateFin', null,
        ]
    ]);
```

You can even put it all into one `where` method call:

```
$query->where(
    ['or',
        ['and',
            [
                'between',
                'str_to_date(\'' . $this->dateRecherche . '\', \'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i\')',
                new Expression('str_to_date(erDateDebut, \'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i\')'),
                new Expression('str_to_date(erDateFin, \'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i\')'),
            ],
            [
                'not', ['erDateFin' => null],
            ]
        ],
        ['and',
            [
                'between',
                'str_to_date(\'' . $this->dateRecherche . '\', \'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i\')',
                new Expression('str_to_date(erDateDebut, \'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i\')'),
                new Expression('now()'),
            ],
            [
                'is', 'erDateFin', null,
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

I have used the [where](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#where%28%29-detail) method, not the [filterWhere](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#filterWhere%28%29-detail) methods, because you probably don't want to remove [empty operands](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#isEmpty%28%29-detail) from the query. More information about filtering can be found [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#filter-conditions). [where](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#where%28%29-detail) also documents the *and* and *or* operators.

As you probably already know, count can be done with

```
$count = $query->count();
```

Comment: Thank you but I have a last question `$query->where();` disable all my previous filters do you know why and how to resolve that ?

Comment: @SamaëlVillette I didn't know that you have further queries. You can use [andWhere](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#andWhere%28%29-detail) or [orWhere](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#orWhere%28%29-detail) instead. But remember that, like the filter methods, nesting is not possible. You combine one condition with another condition by and/or on level 0. It's like you say `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... AND ... OR ...` but not `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... AND ... (... OR ...) `. Nesting can be done with the arrays.